# Creating dictionary from plist and am getting back null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a plist file in my project that looks like this :
[image: plist]

and im doing this

```
NSURL *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"plist"]; //Lets get the file location

    NSDictionary *plistContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:file];
    NSLog(@"dic::%@", plistContent);

     NSArray *arrayRead  = [plistContent allKeys];
    NSLog(@"test::%@", arrayRead);
```

Everything I seem to do returns (null) in my logs. Any ideas why?

Comment: what returns: NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[NSURL fileURLAtPath:file]]; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your plist root is an array, not a dictionary. Use:

```
NSArray *plistContent = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:file];
```

Of course you now have an array of dictionaries. You can't simply ask for `allKeys` anymore.